# Uploading a file to remote server in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

How to uploaded file in Oracle Apex from Client to another Client (The destination folder not on the database server) on mounted folder
Database version is 19C and Apex 21.2

I can upload a file to Oracle database by using Oracle apex. I am able to write the file to database local directory by using UTL_FILE.
But the requirement is to upload the file to remote file server directory(Mounted on the database server)
But I am unable to write the file to mounted directory by using UTIL_FILE.
Anyone can guide me how can I upload the file to remote server.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question is lacking some details - what's preventing you from writing to the mounted directory using UTL_FILE, what operating systems are involved, how is the remote directory mounted on the Oracle server etc. Please [edit] your question and add the missing information.